# How can I access my socket id from client with python-socketio?

Tags: python, python-socketio

I start using `python-socketio` connect `socketIO` `nodejs` server instead of `javascript`, I face problem with socket id:

```py
class LoginSocket(socketio.ClientNamespace):
    def on_connect(self):
        print('connected to server')
        # I need get socket id here to emit to server


        # sio.disconnect()

    def on_python(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(args, kwargs, 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')


    def on_disconnect(self):
        print('disconnected from server')


sio = socketio.Client()
sio.register_namespace(LoginSocket('/'))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sio.connect('https:/sitename.com/')
    sio.wait()
```

..and I can't find any document about `socket.id` from client same `javascript`.
In `javascript` after connect success I can access socket.id like below:

```
 const socket = io.connect('https://socketserver.com/', { 'forceNew': true });
      socket.on('connect', function () {
      alert(socket.id)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be an omission on my part.

You can access the `sid` as `sio.eio.sid`, but I will add a more high-level option as well.

Comment: Thanks, Miguel. Works now also via `sio.sid`.